# PrimePush counter implementation

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, primepush

I am trying to implement prime push counter in my project. I am using PrimeFaces3.5, Jboss7.0 and Eclipse Indigo version.

I have added jars related to prime push:

1. atmosphere-annotations-1.0.1.jar
2. atmosphere-compat-jbossweb-1.0.1.jar
3. atmosphere-compat-tomcat-1.0.1.jar
4. atmosphere-compat-tomcat7-1.0.1.jar
5. atmosphere-runtime-1.0.1.jar
6. primefaces-3.5.jar and jsf and slf4j jars

My xhtml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <h:outputText id="out" value="#{pushBean.count}" />
        <p:commandButton value="Click" actionListener="#{pushBean.increment}" />
    </h:form>
    <p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/counter" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function handleMessage(data) {
           $('.display').html(data);
         }
    </script>
</h:body>
</html>
```

My managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "pushBean")
@ApplicationScoped
public class PushBean {

    public PushBean() {
    }

    private int count;

    public int getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }

    public void setCount(final int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public synchronized void increment() {
        this.count++;
        PushContext pushContext = PushContextFactory.getDefault().getPushContext();
        pushContext.push("/counter", String.valueOf(this.count));
    }

}
```

When I click the button in UI, the count is incremented on the server, but it is not reflected in UI automatically, because it is not updated. But when I refresh the page, the count is incremented as expected.

---

Exception I am getting is:

```
13:00:02,298 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) [http--0.0.0.0-8080-5] ERROR org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - AtmosphereFramework exception

13:00:02,298 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) java.lang.IllegalStateException: The servlet or filters that are being used by this request do not support async operation
```

Comment: You did not mention that you setup the Push Servlet like described in the [primefaces user guide](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/indexed_primefaces_users_guide_3_5.pdf) - chapter 5. Did you configure it?

Comment: Yes Jens, I have configured in web.xml                                   <servlet>
<servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: You try to config in web.xml: <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

Comment: @Sandeep: So i will post as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception happens when your web app is run in Servlet 3 compliant containers. The correct web.xml must have the async-supported element set to true, for example:

```
    <servlet> 
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name> 
        <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class> 
        <async-supported>true</async-supported> 
    </servlet>
```

Reference: [Installing Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Installing-Atmosphere)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure about push framework but i think the problem is with your javascript.
you are trying to refresh ".display" control but there is nothing like .display.

Try '.out' instead of .display

Comment: I have changed the code to use ajax update instead of javascript... even then same result...                                       <h:form id="form">
  <h:outputText id="out" value="#{pushBean.count}" />
  <p:commandButton value="Click" actionListener="#{pushBean.increment}" />
 </h:form>
 <p:socket channel="/counter">
  <p:ajax event="message" update="form:out" />
 </p:socket>